# Memory usage increase on QFX5100-24Q virtual chassis

Tags: juniper

I have a pair of Juniper QFX5100-24Q in virtual chassis mode, and I am using 18.4R2-S2.4 for both devices, and I have a few SVI with 15x BGP session.
One of my BGP sessions is receiving 200k routes, but I am rejecting them by import policy, and I do not have them in my route tables.
Juniper QFX5100-24Q master device is using %77 memory but Juniper QFX5100-24Q, which is in backup mode, is using %90 memory. A few months ago it was %70 and it is increasing by %1 every 1-2weeks.
Also, when I checked memory usages by show task memory commands it shows memory usages is %5.
Here is the output:

```
Memory                 Size (kB)  Percentage  When
  Currently In Use:       110858          5%  now
  Maximum Ever Used:      191406          9%  23/10/23 09:18:36
  Available:             1992294        100%  now
```

Here is another information:

```
run show system processes extensive
last pid: 44690;  load averages:  0.29,  0.17,  0.16  up 88+20:37:42    06:05:55
174 processes: 3 running, 150 sleeping, 21 waiting

Mem: 903M Active, 259M Inact, 509M Wired, 104M Cache, 69M Buf, 73M Free
Swap: 1106M Total, 1106M Free


  PID USERNAME     PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME   WCPU COMMAND
   10 root         155   52     0K    12K RUN    1727.5 84.18% idle
 8228 root          41    0  1201M   582M select 293.1H 10.64% fxpc
 8229 root          40    0   100M 31256K select 903:52  0.15% chassisd
 8228 root         -52  -52  1201M   582M select 293.1H  0.00% fxpc
 8223 root          40    0 52976K 38344K select 740:49  0.00% mib2d
   11 root         -56 -159     0K    12K WAIT   469:01  0.00% swi2: netisr 0
 8222 root           4    0   352M   251M kqread 449:10  0.00% rpd
 8222 root           4    0   352M   251M kqread 449:10  0.00% rpd
```

I am worried that it will reach %100 on backup chassis and I will face an issue.
As a note, memory utilization is increasing just for backup devices, and master device is same since many months ago.
Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Can you explain how you concluded that 90% memory is used by backup device?

Comment: i used show chassis routing-engine to check the memory utilization

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact commands and their output where you see the problem. Also, 18.4 seems to be quite aged - have you considered updating the switches?